# Prime sieve generator

Tags: python, python-2.x, sieve-of-eratosthenes, generator

I wrote a simple prime sieve in Python. But it ended up looking... ugly. I included a few of the most basic optimizations. When posting this question SE suggested a bunch of questions on the same topic, which lead me to some improvements. But few were in generator form.

It's the optimizations' fault.
Unfortunately I can't `continue` an outer loop from an inner loop, like I can in JavaScript. I very much disagree with Guido [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1859147/802363), as it makes the inner loop clunky.

```py
from itertools import count

def sieve():
    primes = [2]
    for candidate in count(start=3, step=2):
        cont = False
        n = 0
        while primes[n]**2 <= candidate:  # You only need to check up to the square root of a number.
            if candidate % primes[n] == 0:
                cont = True  # outer
                break
            n = n + 1
        if cont:
            cont = False
            continue
        yield primes[-1]
        primes.append(candidate)
```

Can we make this more concise without changing the basic logic?
For example [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6698/203088) is extremely concise, but it doesn't have some of the optimizations my code does.

For fun, I wrote the same logic in Javascript. This looks cleaner due to being able to continue an outer loop. But the lack of negative indices is a step backwards.

> ```javascript
> function* sieve() {
>     let primes = [2]
>     counter: for (let candidate = 3;; candidate+=2) {
>         for (let n = 1; primes[n]**2 <= candidate; n++)
>             if (candidate % primes[n] == 0)
>                 continue counter
>         yield primes[primes.length - 1]
>         primes.push(candidate)
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Please pick one language per question. Do you want the Python or the JavaScript reviewed?

Comment: Hm, if I have to choose, I guess I'll go with python.

Comment: Note that what you are implementing here is *not* the Sieve of Eratosthenes, but rather the oft-mistaken and much slower Trial Division algorithm. The Sieve has no divisions nor modulo operations in it and accomplishes everything through additions or, at worst, some multiplications.

Comment: You can compare Trial Division (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) to the Sieve of Eratosthenes here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 6):

1. We can move the while loop into another function.

   ```py
   def is_prime(candidate, primes):
       n = 0
       while primes[n]**2 <= candidate:
           if candidate % primes[n] == 0:
               return False
           n += 1
       return True

   def sieve():
       primes = [2]
       for candidate in count(start=3, step=2):
           if not is_prime(candidate, primes):
               continue
           yield primes[-1]
           primes.append(candidate)
   ```
2. We can use `itertools.takewhile` to expose the while loop as an iterable.

   ```py
   def is_prime(candidate, primes):
       for prime in itertools.takewhile(lambda p: p**2 <= candidate, primes):
           if candidate % prime == 0:
               return False
       return True
   ```
3. We can use `any` to make `is_prime` easier to read.

   If for any of the values, `candidate % prime == 0`, are true the result is true.
   If none of them are then it is false.
   Since we want it to be the other way around we can just use `not`.

   ```py
   def is_prime(candidate, primes):
       return not any(
           candidate % prime == 0
           for prime in itertools.takewhile(lambda p: p**2 <= candidate, primes)
       )
   ```
4. We can move `is_prime` back into the first function.

   ```py
   def sieve():
       primes = [2]
       for candidate in count(start=3, step=2):
           if not not any(
               candidate % prime == 0
               for prime in itertools.takewhile(lambda p: p**2 <= candidate, primes)
           ):
               continue
           yield primes[-1]
           primes.append(candidate)
   ```
5. We can swap the `if` to cancel the `continue` and a `not`.
6. We can swap the `any` and `== 0`, with `not all`.
7. We can cancel the double `not`.

```py
def sieve():
    primes = [2]
    for candidate in count(start=3, step=2):
        if all(
            candidate % prime
            for prime in itertools.takewhile(lambda p: p**2 <= candidate, primes)
        ):
            yield primes[-1]
            primes.append(candidate)
```

At the expense of readability you can get the following trade offs.

1. There is a chance that using `int(candidate ** 0.5).__ge__` is faster than the `lambda`.

Comment: While this is a good explanation of the approach, I am sad to report that it is also wrong - the logic is broken. It thinks 9 is a prime. More generally, it considers all odd squares prime.

Comment: Though the fix is simple - the lambda condition must be `<=`, not `<`. I do like how mathematically / logically this is more expressive than the other answer. It is also slower(15.1s vs 12.9s over n=200K). TBH I can't decide which answer is better...

Comment: @martixy Ah yes I dropped the equals there, but somehow kept it in the 'extra' part - `__ge__`. Thank you. You didn't highlight that you wanted this super optimized, however if you do then [another one of my answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/213422/42401) likely performs better than either of these answers.

Comment: Not specifically "super optimized", I was just listing pros and cons.

Comment: I like everything in this answer except the implicit conversion of a remainder to a truthy value: to me, `candidate % prime != 0` is vastly more readable, despite being a minimal change.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm guessing you disagree with 2.1 too :P I had originally put it as 2.2 for that reason but then 1.6 wouldn't make as much sense :(

Comment: @Peilonrayz You’ve lost me.

Comment: Maybe my x.y notation is unclear? x is the referring to one of the ordered lists, 1 -> first ordered list. y is the number of the item in the list. E.g. 1.6 -> "We can swap the `any` and `== 0`, with `not all`." I think I should start the second list from the end of the first list in the future.

Answer (score 5):

This outputs the same as your function:

```py
import array
from itertools import count


def sieve():
    primes = array.array("L", [2])  # L: unsigned long int
    for candidate in count(start=3, step=2):
        n = 0
        while primes[n] ** 2 <= candidate:
            if candidate % primes[n] == 0:
                break
            n += 1
        else:  # nobreak
            yield primes[-1]
            primes.append(candidate)


n = 0
primes = sieve()

while True:
    prime = next(primes)
    print(prime)
    n += 1
```

I did not touch the algorithm itself because I am unfamiliar, but Python (tested on 3.8.2, but also runs on 2.7.18, as you seem to need given your tag [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x)) has the `while`/`else` construct that can help you with your control flow here.

A `break break`, `break <label>` or similar thinkable constructs have been [proposed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/), as you linked as well, but rejected.
A possible remedy is to extract sub-routines into functions and to use their `return` statements for control flow/multi-level breaking.
In your case, that is not needed.

The `while`/`else` construct is unfamiliar to many. In fact, it is so alien that Guido [would not implement it again](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-October/006157.html) nowadays.
For now, it is best to think of the `else` as `nobreak`: the `while` loop finished normally (its condition evaluated to `False`) and exited.
Since *no* `break` occurred, the `else` block is executed.

In the above case, if `break` is hit in the `if` block, the `else` is *skipped*: no `yield` occurs, and since after the `else` block, there is no code left, a `continue` for the outer `for` loop is implied and not explicitly necessary, since there is nothing else to do anyway.

---

A frequent example is in the form of `for`/`else` (which works like the `while`/`else`) when looking for a hit, like in your case:

```py
for file in files:
    if file == file_looked_for:
        file.do_something()
        break
else:  # nobreak
    # code to handle file not found
```

So while, like you, I have been tripped up by the lack of advanced `break` functionalities, I agree with Guido.
Apart from the unfortunate naming of `else` in the `while` construct (more discussion [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17169331)), it can do the job just fine.
Trying to break through multiple levels is an occasion to rethink the implementation.

---

Other observations:

- `primes[n]` has to call `__getitem__`, which happens twice. This is constant-time, but the following will probably provide a speed-up (but requires the "walrus" operator from Python 3.8):

  ```py
    while (
        (prime := primes[n]) ** 2 <= candidate
    ):  # You only need to check up to the square root of a number.
        if candidate % prime == 0:
  ```

  `primes` no longer has to be looked up, the simple, local `prime` suffices for the second call.
- `n = n + 1` can be `n += 1`. However, this is possibly slower.
- Finally, the built-in `array.array` can be much faster than a `list`. This is because `list`s can hold arbitrary objects, whereas an `array` has to be initiliazed for a specific one (here: `L` for `long int`, which will [last a while](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/limits.h)). As a positive consequence, the `array` can then be optimized accordingly.

  Note how `array.array`, in this case, is a 1:1 drop-in for the previous `list`. As such, the code did not have to change. As such, it is also easy for you to revert the change if unwanted.

Comment: You can change the calling code in your first code block to just `for prime in sieve(): print(prime)`.

Comment: Yes you are right. There was a guard clause to `break` at `n == 20` that felt more natural in a `while True`, but I removed it before posting.

Comment: In the future you may wish to do `for i, prime in enumerate(sieve()): if i == 20: break` it's more 'Pythonic' ;)

Comment: `alien` > You can say that again. I initially thought you'd messed up your indentation before reading the explanation. While the construct looks odd (and `else` is a questionable choice of words), it does make it pretty neat - and faster. For the other observations: Walrus operator - this is just a straight up a _holy crap, wtf python?_ moment - why is the same thing that works for a million other languages not enough for python? Why does there have to be a special operator? Also provides at best a marginal improvement (12.9s > 12.6s over n=200K). Continued...

Comment: And I am sad to report that `array.array` actually results in a slowdown. For `n += 1` - I know python doesn't have `++` and I was under the mistaken impression shorthand assignment is also not in there. Regardless, if `n += 1` is slower, it is not observable over n=200K. Thank you for the review. It's a good explanation of a language construct I've never encountered before. The other observations also fit in the spirit of the question, even if they end up being hit or miss. Python is just like that special child(walrus - _seriously? I can't even..._)

Comment: Thanks for you feedback, interesting to see. Well, some just call it "walrus", but its official fancy name is [Assignment Operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/). `array.array` being a slowdown is surprising! I can confirm that observation. Even `"I"` instead of `"L"` is slower. At this point, `numpy` could be the next thing to try out, if you want more optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Three main things vex me about your code:

- the just generated prime isn't returned,
- the boolean test a the end of the `while` loop
- repeated prime "square and test" for candidacy.

## Not returning generated prime

Your code generates `3`, and yields `2`, then it generates `5` and yields `3`, then it generates `7` and yields `5`, then generates `11` and yields `7`, and so on.

This happens because you half treat `2` as a special case.  You initialize the `primes` array with it.  But to return it, you use `yield primes[-1]` just like every other prime.

If you treated it completely as a special case, and yield it right off the hop, you could `yield candidate` at the end of the loop, thus returning the prime you just computed.

```
def sieve():
    primes = [2]
    yield 2

    for candidate in count(start=3, step=2):
        ...
        yield candidate
        primes.append(candidate)
```

## Unnecessary boolean test at end of while

A `while` loop is often used for searching.  If the value is found, the `while` loop is escaped via a `break` statement.  If the while loop completes without ever breaking, the condition searched for was never found, and something different needs to happen.  In Python, this is the `while ... else` statement:

```
def sieve():
    primes = [2]
    yield 2
    for candidate in count(start=3, step=2):
        n = 0
        while primes[n]**2 <= candidate:  # Only check up to the square root of number.
            if candidate % primes[n] == 0:
                break
            n = n + 1
        else:
            yield candidate
            primes.append(candidate)
```

## Repeated prime "square and test" for candidacy.

How often is the `primes[n]**2 <= candidate` done?

If `candidate` is just over 10,000, and is prime, then we will be squaring all primes less than 100, and testing that they are less than `candidate`.  Then, we do the same thing for `candidate + 2`, and the results will be the same.  No prime number less than 100, squared, will ever be greater than `candidate` once `candidate` exceeds 10,000 ... so this is all busy work, repeating the same test over and over.

What you need is to partition your `primes` list into two parts: primes less or equal to the square-root of candidate, and primes greater the square-root of candidate.

You can do this in several ways.  The smallest change would be to keep track of a count of "small" primes.  As `candidate` gets larger by 2, you would only need add at most one more prime into the "small" primes bucket:

```
def sieve():
    primes = [2]
    yield 2

    small_primes = 0
    for candidate in count(start=3, step=2):

        if primes[small_primes] ** 2 <= candidate:
            small_primes += 1

        for n in range(small_primes):
             if candidate % primes[n] == 0:
                break
        else:
            yield candidate
            primes.append(candidate)
```

Now how often is `primes[small_primes] ** 2 <= candidate` being done?  Once per candidate!  This has got to be an improvement.  Also, all `n = 0` and `n = n + 1` code has been absorbed into `for n in range(small_primes)`, and having Python do this work is faster than coding it ourselves.

## Other improvements

### Odd numbers

Why are we test-dividing all of our candidates by `primes[0] == 2`?  By design, they are all odd, and can never be evenly divided by 2.

```
        for n in range(1, small_primes):    # Skip divide-by-2 tests
```

### All

As mentioned by Peilonrayz, Python has an `any()` function, though I think `all()` is more appropriate here.

```
def sieve():
    primes = [2]
    yield 2

    small_primes = 0
    for candidate in count(start=3, step=2):

        if primes[small_primes] ** 2 <= candidate:
            small_primes += 1

        if all(candidate % primes[n] != 0 for n in range(1, small_primes)):
            yield candidate
            primes.append(candidate)
```

### Maintain separate lists

Instead of `small_primes` being a count of the number of primes less than the square-root of the `candidate`, what if it actually was a list of the small prime numbers?  And instead of adding prime candidates to that list, we add to a `large_primes` list?  Then we could move primes from the `large_primes` to the `small_primes` as the square-root of the candidate increases.

Optimizations:

- `deque` for `large_primes`
- Omit `2` from the `small_primes` list,
- Cache the `large_prime[0] ** 2` value, to avoid repeatedly squaring the same quantity.

Resulting code:

```
from itertools import count
from collections import deque

def sieve():
    yield 2
    yield 3

    small_primes = []
    large_primes = deque((3,))
    next_prime_squared = large_primes[0] ** 2

    for candidate in count(start=5, step=2):

        if candidate >= next_prime_squared:
            small_primes.append(large_primes.popleft())
            next_prime_squared = large_primes[0] ** 2

        if all(candidate % prime != 0 for prime in small_primes):
            yield candidate
            large_primes.append(candidate)
```

## Time Comparisons

Time (in seconds) for generating 100 to 100,000 primes:
[image]

Timing code:

```
import array
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import count, takewhile
from collections import deque
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def martixy():
    primes = [2]
    for candidate in count(start=3, step=2):
        cont = False
        n = 0
        while primes[n]**2 <= candidate:  # You only need to check up to the square root of a number.
            if candidate % primes[n] == 0:
                cont = True  # outer
                break
            n = n + 1
        if cont:
            cont = False
            continue
        yield primes[-1]
        primes.append(candidate)

def alex_povel():
    primes = array.array("L", [2])  # L: unsigned long int
    for candidate in count(start=3, step=2):
        n = 0
        while primes[n] ** 2 <= candidate:
            if candidate % primes[n] == 0:
                break
            n += 1
        else:  # nobreak
            yield primes[-1]
            primes.append(candidate)

def peilonrayz():
    primes = [2]
    for candidate in count(start=3, step=2):
        if all(
            candidate % prime
            for prime in takewhile(lambda p: p**2 <= candidate, primes)
        ):
            yield primes[-1]
            primes.append(candidate)

def ajneufeld():
    yield 2
    yield 3

    small_primes = []
    large_primes = deque((3,))
    next_prime_squared = large_primes[0] ** 2

    for candidate in count(start=5, step=2):

        if candidate >= next_prime_squared:
            small_primes.append(large_primes.popleft())
            next_prime_squared = large_primes[0] ** 2

        if all(candidate % prime != 0 for prime in small_primes):
            yield candidate
            large_primes.append(candidate)

def test(candidate, limit):
    sieve = candidate()
    for _ in range(limit):
        next(sieve)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    candidates = (martixy, alex_povel, peilonrayz, ajneufeld)
    limits = [int(10 ** (power * 0.25)) for power in range(8, 21)]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    for candidate in candidates:
        print("Testing", candidate.__name__)
        times = [ timeit(lambda: test(candidate, limit), number=1) for limit in limits ]
        ax.plot(limits, times, '-+', label=candidate.__name__)

    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```